# How do I upgrade ember-data to a specific sha in ember-cli?

Tags: ember-data, ember-cli

I want to lock down my ember-cli project's version of ember-data to [this commit](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/f97d5c9adbabd7f6b4935e614bc95e49b66bb7e0), which updates the map function signatures and lets ED work with Ember 1.8.

I tried using the [canary instructions](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-canary-build-instead-of-release) as a template and doing this, and adding this to my `bower.json`:

```
"ember-data": "components/ember-data#f97d5c9adbabd7f6b4935e614bc95e49b66bb7e0",
```

and

```
"resolutions": {
  "ember-data": "#f97d5c9adbabd7f6b4935e614bc95e49b66bb7e0"
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> Additional error details:
>   fatal: reference is not a tree: f97d5c9adbabd7f6b4935e614bc95e49b66bb7e0

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

You'll need to reference the sha in the canary branch of components/ember-data, not the one from emberjs/ember-data.

In your case the sha you want is `11715a514ec33ed32438d818ee501865cd4cd2c7` [commit here](https://github.com/components/ember-data/commit/11715a514ec33ed32438d818ee501865cd4cd2c7)

Update your sha's to that and you're good to go!

**How I found this info:**

The components/ember-data github repo autobuilds a new version on the canary branch with each commit to ember-data. The way I found the sha you needed is by looking at the [commit history](https://github.com/components/ember-data/commits/canary?page=2) and finding the same day, and then the comment that contained the sha you wanted