# How do I use my fork of ember-data in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm working on a pull-request for ember-data, and I'd like to be able to test these changes in my ember-cli app.

It doesn't work to follow the directions for using canary [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635615/how-do-i-upgrade-ember-data-to-a-specific-sha-in-ember-cli) or [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-canary-build-instead-of-release), as my fork does not get built my `components`.

I've tried referencing my fork and branch in `packages.json` as well as `bower.json`; then I get this error:

```
Path or pattern "bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js" did not match any files
```

I can then build ember-data manually and copy the file to `bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js`. However, I would like a streamlined way to use a fork of ember-data so I can use and test my pull-request without a lengthy install process.

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are trying to use the NPM package of `ember-data` with Bower, and Bower needs `ember-data` to be precompiled. You were correct to fork [emberjs/data](https://github.com/emberjs/data) and reference your fork in `package.json`. Here is how I compiled my fork for bower:

In your forked repo, run `npm install` and `npm run build:production` to compile your fork in the `dist` directory.

Then fork the `ember-data` shim for bower: [components/ember-data](https://github.com/components/ember-data). Copy the following files from your `ember-data` fork's `dist` directory into the shim's directory:

- `bower.json`
- `component.json`
- `composer.json`
- `ember-data.js`
- `ember-data.js.map`
- `ember-data.min.js`
- `ember-data.prod.js`
- `package.json`

Edit the bower/package files if you want to add your own version tag. Commit the shim repo to a branch or master, and then reference that commit in your `ember-cli` app's `bower.json` file. Then run `npm install` and `bower install` in your `ember-cli` app.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a symlink to your local version of a bower and/or npm dependency.

Go to your local (forked) version of ember-data and

```
npm link
bower link
```

This will make a global symlink to your local version.

Then go to where you're using the dependency and

```
npm link ember-data
bower link ember-data
```

This will make `node_modules/ember-data` and `bower_components/ember-data` a symlink to your local version.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link and http://bower.io/docs/api/#link for more details on how these work.